# Comparing Euclidean distances using a vector and its projection

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

Say we have $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $D\in\mathbb{R}$. Define a corresponding vector $y=[y_1\cdots y_n]$ to be the projection of $x$ onto the $n$-cube of side length $2D$ centered at the origin, i.e. we define $y$ in the following manner: $$y_i=\begin{cases}x_i&|x_i|\le D\\D&x_i>D\\-D&x_i<-D\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\;\forall i\in [n]$$What I am wondering (and hoping to show) is whether $\|y-Jy\|\le\|x-Jx\|$ where $J$ is the $n\times n$ matrix where each entry is $1/n$. Intuitively, it seems clear. Geometrically, (2-dimensional case) it also seems pretty clear. I just cannot extend to arbitrary dimensions.

My attempt to show this began with my trying to use a polarization identity, specifically $\|a-b\|^2=\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2-2(a\cdot b)$, but I get stuck because I cannot assume $\|Jy\|\le\|Jx\|$. I am at a loss. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.